# How do I add Xi Editor to my Applications folder?

Tags: macos

How would I go about adding Google's Xi Editor to my app folder so I don't have to run it from command line?

I haven't really tried anything because I have no idea how to do this properly.

https://github.com/google/xi-editor

Answer (score 2):

So this turned out to be pretty easy if anybody else is wondering.

When you build the project an .app file get create in build/Release/

You can simply drag this into the applications folder using Finder. Easy!